# getting jsonarray api but not sure when it return jsonobject and when it return jsonarray

Tags: android, json

I am confused that one time if single image there then I will get JSON response like this from my API,

```
{
  "banners": 
{
    "imagepath": "myimg.jpg"
  }
}
```

And if more than one image there then I get result like this,

```
   {
  "banners": {
    "imagepath": [
      "myimg.jpg",
      "myimg1.jpg"
    ]
  }
}
```

How do I handle both result at a same time using JSON parsing?

Comment: I personally think the API is designed badly. Did you create it? If so, whenever your API only can return 1 image, make it return a list of 1 image. This way you only need one parser for your endpoint.

Comment: no i havent create this api. I also feel the same but my developer says it is not possible from their side. So its useful if we get it from android side. Thanks anyway @ZUNJAE

Comment: if u use JSONObject, then you get use `JSONObject.get("imagepath")` and `instanceof` to check of what type it is. Depending on the type you manually parse this variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can't change the API response then you have to parse the JSON manually like below.

```
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response); 
    JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonObject.getJSONObject("banners"); 
    //check the banners is the JSONArray or not
     if (jsonObject1.get("imagepath") instanceof JSONArray) {
    //code for JSON Array
    }else{
    //code for simple one
    }
```